# Ending a session/clearing cookies

Tags: php

Ok, so I've got some legacy code from another company that I have to maintain/repair. One of the features of this code is that there are several sites tied to this one main site, and whenever you navigate from the other sites to this site, a logo from the other site is displayed on the main site (basically this is a service for multiple banks to use, and each bank wants its own branding).

The problem is is that once you navigate from, say, site1 to main site, if you then navigate from site2 to main site, you'll still get site1's branding.

Is there a way to clear a session's cookies? So far they've got code like this, which should THEORETICALLY work:

```
    else
    {
        setcookie("cuid","",time() - 31536000); //DELETES COOKIE

        if( $cuid_demo!="samplecu" && $cuid!="samplecu" )
            setcookie("cuid",$cuid,time()+2592000); //2592000 = 1 month

        $link=dbconnect();

        if(!$link)
            die("error: Could not connect to database - ".dberror() );

        select_db($link) or die("error: ".dberror() );

        if (isset($admin_id))
        {
            $cuid = $admin_id;
            $id = $admin_id;
        }

        $query="UPDATE cusucceed SET visits=visits+1 WHERE id = '$cuid'";
        $result=dbquery($link, $query)or die("Database Server Error 2: ".dberror());
        include("index_main.php");

    } //END IF/ELSE TO CHECK FOR PREVIOUS VISIT WITH THE PAST MONTH
}
```

Before it does nothing. Shouldn't `setcookie("cuid", "", time() - 31536000);` delete the cookie, as the comments say?

Comment: Just a note: The error messages that are spit out by PHP are not intended for the public but only for developers as it may [reveal sensitive information](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Information_Leakage).

Comment: I know, I don't do that in my own code - my company was merely hired to fix the cookie problem. The company that hired us doesn't have the budget for me to fix the error messages, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set correct domain for cookie when you reset it.

```
setcookie('name', NULL, -86400, 'cookie_path', 'subdomain.site1.com');
```

Comment: How would I find this information? Cookies is one thing I'm still learning about (this is definitely good experience for it, though)

Comment: if you work with domain name andrew.com for example, you need to set cookie like this: **setcookie('name', NULL, -86400, '/', 'andrew.com');**

Comment: Yes, but what about like 'cookie_path'? And the files I am working with are on the main site, so could I then do www.mainsite.com? Or does it have to be from the referrer?

Comment: Set cookie path to / for whole site. You can also set path to any directory like /supersecdir, and this cookie will work only with this directory. But you can't set cookie from domain andrew.com to domain billy.com. You can avoid it with setting an 1x1 png image with get param from billy.com, then when user on andrew.com opens a page, he fetches this image and billy.com sets a cookie with andrew.com ID.